# packages excluded due to repository priority protections

Tags: linux, centos-6

I am not able to update my PHP in centos 6.

I have centos base, epel and rpmforge repos.

```
yum update php
```

```
Error: Package: php-tidy-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (@updates)
Requires: php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
Removing: php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (@updates)
php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
Updated By: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
php-common = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
php-common = 5.3.3-22.el6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
.. install failed!
```

I believe php-tidy has been excluded due to repo priority.
How do it fix it?

**EDIT**
epel.repo has "priority = 10"
Could it be a reason?

```
yum update -d3
```

gives list of excluded updates. 
--> php-tidy-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 from base excluded (priority)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to disable extra repositories while trying to upgrade packages.

There are some tricks that you can try when you have multiple repositories that contain different versions of the same package. CentOS has [this wiki article](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/YumAndRPM) with some tips and tricks for specifying a certain repository to use.

Using this information, running

```
yum --disablerepo "*" --enablerepo "updates" update php
```

should clear up this issue.

Comment: "No Packages marked for Update." I guess it is because PHP updates are in base.

Comment: --> php-tidy-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 from base excluded (priority) - This is causing the problem. I m not able to fix it

Comment: Have you tried disabling the repositories as suggested and enabling the repository you're trying to install php from? You most likely have conflicting priorities. Can you `grep -ri priority /etc/yum.*` and update your question with this output?

Comment: I tried the command in your answer. Tried both epel and rpmforge both says "No package marked for update." grep for priority says epel.repo has priority = 10

Comment: Most likely. Give `yum --disablerepo "*" --enablerepo "base updates" update php` a shot.

Comment: `Error getting repository data for base updates, repository not found.`

Comment: Yeah, that was my fault. I realized it shortly after running that same command on my test box. It should be `yum --disablerepo "*" --enablerepo "updates" update php`.